# Why would you use gorilla/context instead of session for user authentication?

Tags: session, cookies, go, gorilla

I understand the difference between **context** and **session** in `golang`.

`gorilla/context` stores values shared during a request lifetime whereas `gorilla/session` data persists across multiple requests through secure cookie.

Some blogs claim that **context is required** to pass user data from one middleware to another.

For user authentication, you would have to store user data in session **anyways** and **why** would you store user data into context as well?

I suppose it is so that you don't have to get user data from **session (cookie)** again but it seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The [gorilla/sessions](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/sessions) package uses [gorilla/context](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/context) in its implementation.

If the application uses session data to store id of the authenticated user, then the application does not need use the gorilla/context package directly.

Comment: So gorilla/sessions persists data into securecookie but also keeps copy in context for access? Looks like it caches session into context upon Save()